# Web Browser object equivalent in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there an equivalent object, in Android Studio, that has the same functionality as the WKWebViewController in Xcode, Ojective C?

The idea is to present the user with a webpage page using a web browser (preferably Chrome), the user does some work on the webpage, and lastly when the work is done closing the web browser (preferably dynamically) and go into the app.

In Xcode, Objective C, on the viewDidLoad function, I have something like this:

```
   WKWebViewConfiguration *configureWebView = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
   configureWebView.applicationNameForUserAgent = @"Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5";
   WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame 
   configuration:configureWebView];
   webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"a websites goes here"];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
    webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
    self.view addSubview:webView];
```

In Android Studio is there an object that is similar to the WkWebView object that I can use to control a web-browser; have it launch as an app starts up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `WebView` class

You can put a `WebView` inside your layout xml file as so

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

In order to load a web url into the WebView, you need to call a method loadUrl(String url) of the WebView class, specifying the required url. Its syntax is:

```
browser.loadUrl("http://www.tutorialspoint.com");
```

You can find more details regarding this [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm)

And well to answer your question `have it launch as the app starts up`, you can override the `onCreate` of your first `Activity` instance and do it. This is equivalent to the `viewDidLoad` of Objective-C and IOS View in general

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I was looking for; an Android object that does something similar to what the WKWebView does in Obj. C for iOS.